# What is Opening a file in C?

Tags: c, file

In C when we open a file what happens?? As I know that the contents of the file is not loaded in the memory when we open a file. It just sets the file descriptor ? So what is this file descriptor then?? And  if the contents of the file is not loaded in the memory then how a file is opened?

Comment: What function are you using to open the file?

Answer (score 6):

Typically, if you're opening a file with `fopen` or (on a POSIX system) `open`, the function, if successful, will "open the file" - it merely gives you a value (a `FILE *` or an `int`) to use in future calls to a read function.

Under the hood, the operating system *might* read some or all of the file in, it might not. You have to call some function to request data to be read anyways, and if it hasn't done it by the time you call `fread`/`fgets`/`read`/etc... then it will at that point.

A "file descriptor" typically refers to the integer returned by `open` in POSIX systems. It is used to identify an open file. If you get a value `3`, somewhere, the operating system is keeping track that `3` refers to `/home/user/dir/file.txt`, or whatever. It's a short little value to indicate to the OS *which* file to read from. When you call `open`, and open say, `foo.txt`, the OS says, "ok, file open, calling it `3` from here on".

Answer (score 4):

This question is not entirely related to the programming language. Although the library does have an impact on what happens when opening a file (using `open` or `fopen`, for example), the main behavior comes from the operating system.

Linux, and I assume other OSs perform read ahead in most cases. This means that the file is actually read from the physical storage even before you call `read` for the file. This is done as an optimization, reducing the time for the read when the file is actually read by the user. This behavior can be controlled partially by the programmer, using specific flag for the open functions. For example, the Win32 API `CreateFile` can specify `FILE_FLAG_RANDOM_ACCESS` or `FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN` to specify random access (in which case the file is not read ahead) or sequential access (in which case the OS will perform quite aggressive read ahead), respectively. Other OS APIs might give more or less control.

For the basic ANSI C API of `open`, `read`, `write` that use a file descriptor, the file descriptor is a simple integer that is passed onto the OS and signifies the file. In the OS itself this is most often translated to some structure that contains all the needed information for the file (name, path, seek offsets, size, read and write buffers, etc.). The OS will open the file - meaning find the specific file system entry (an `inode` under Linux) that correlates to the path you've given in the `open` method, creates the file structure and return an ID to the user - the file descriptor. From that point on the OS is free to read whatever data it seems fit, even if not requested by the user (reading more than was requested is often done, to at least work in the file system native size).

Answer (score 2):

C has no primitives for file I/O, it all depends on what operating system 
and what libraries you are using.

Comment: `fopen` is C's primitive for file I/O, and is not OS dependent. (Although you can often make calls to OS specific functions for more control.)

Comment: That's not entirely correct. `fopen` is a library function, not a primitive. Also, since file access is always done by the OS, `fopen` is indeed OS dependent. On one OS `fopen` might be able to read ahead or buffer writes, on another it might not.

Comment: not only that, but the format of the string fopen refers to is entirely OS dependent.  Three popular choices use / \ or : as the

Answer (score 1):

File descriptors are just abstracts. Everything is done on the operating system.

Answer (score 1):

If the program uses `fopen()` then a buffering package will use an implementation-specific *system call* to get a file descriptor and it will store it in a `FILE` structure.

The system call (at least on Unix, Linux, and the Mac) will look around on (usually) a disk-based filesystem to find the file. It creates data structures in the kernel memory that collects the information needed to read or write the file.

It also creates a table for each process that links to the other kernel data structures necessary to access the file. The index into this table is a (usually) small number. This is the file descriptor that is returned from the system call to the user process, and then stored in the FILE struct.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned it is OS functionality.

But for C file I/O most probably you need info on `fopen` function.

If you will check description for that function, it says :

> **Description:**
>
> Opens a stream.
>
> fopen opens the file named by
>   filename and associates a stream with
>   it. fopen returns a pointer to be used
>   to identify the stream in subsequent
>   operations.

So on successful completion `fopen` just returns a pointer to the newly opened stream. And it returns NULL in case of any error.

Answer (score 0):

When you open the file then the **file pointer** gets the **base address**(starting address)of that file.Then you use different functions to work on the file.
EDIT:
Thanks to Chris,here is the structure which is named FILE

```
typedef struct  {
       int             level;      /* fill/empty level of buffer */
       unsigned        flags;      /* File status flags          */
       char            fd;         /* File descriptor            */
       unsigned char   hold;       /* Ungetc char if no buffer   */
       int             bsize;      /* Buffer size                */
       unsigned char   *buffer;    /* Data transfer buffer       */
       unsigned char   *curp;      /* Current active pointer     */
       unsigned        istemp;     /* Temporary file indicator   */
       short           token;      /* Used for validity checking */
}      FILE;
```

Comment: Not exactly.  The "file pointer" to a stream (which may be to a literal file or something else) is not actually a pointer to the file's data, but instead is a pointer to a structure which stores access information including the underlying file descriptor and the read pointer.  The read pointer would normally be initialized to the beginning of the file.  But the fopen() function returns a pointer to the structure, not to the data in the file.  To get an actual dereferencable pointer to the file's data, use open() to get a file descriptor (rather than fopen()) and then mmap() it.

Comment: File structures are OS dependent.  Some structures may contain the logical sector and platter number of the start of the file.  Others may contain permissions and the file name.